# How to use text as a c# code in asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, compilation

I am getting api response in json format. Json response structure can be different on every time that's why I want to fetch the value dynamically from Json response.

Json response can be as below(response structure can be different on every time):

```
{
    "userDetails": [{
            "firstName": "Howard",
            "lastName": "Krispy",
            "userId": "1001"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Leo",
            "lastName": "Stenly",
            "userId": "1002"
        }
    ]
}
```

code is as below:

```
JObject apiResponse= JObject.Parse(result);
string responseKey1 = @"apiResponse[""userDetails""][0][""userId""].ToString()";

var result = responseKey1; //It's giving result "apiResponse[userDetails][0][userId]"
```

I want to fetch the value from the json response. As I mentioned above result should contain
"1001" instead of "apiResponse[userDetails][0][userId]". I have spent couple of days to find the solution but didn't get any proper solution for achieve the result.

So how can I achieve this result?

Comment: Your code just concatenates a string and never touches the `apiResponse` object, have you tried actually accessing the response?

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the fact that you're simply constructing a string that coincidently contains code.

Comment: Actually `apiResponse` is mentioned in the `responseKey1`. However an `apiResponse` contains the json response. So It should fetch the value from the json response. If I write the same key with the result then it's fetching the proper result from the json response.

Comment: Try this: ```string responseKey1 = apiResponse["userDetails"][0]["userId"].ToString();```

Comment: Yes so I want to run the code which I am getting from the db and want to fetch the value from the response dynamically.

Comment: @Harsh You are correct that `apiResponse` contains the json response turned into an object, but your code only deals with `"apiResponse"` which isnt an object at all, its just a string...

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes it can be view as type casting. It's not just about outer quotes. I have already tried that solution also. I have removed the outer quotes by using the trim. But was not solving it.

Comment: @maccettura Yes that's my point. System will contains many types of json response based on user and each user will select what values they want from the json response. That's why json key will store in db and from the db system will fetch the json key and from response it will fetch the values what user wants. Do you think it's type casting problem as `@gunr2171` described?

Comment: @Harsh I think you need to read again what @gunr2171 and I are saying. This line: `string responseKey1 = @"apiResponse[""userDetails""][0][""userId""].ToString()";` is just you _creating a string_, it has absolutely *nothing* to do with the `apiResponse` object, it does not use it in any way shape or form. You just created a string that has the literal value of: "apiResponse[""userDetails""][0][""userId""].ToString()"

Comment: @maccettura okay I got it. So any alternative suggestion to achieve it? Yes it's printing string in `responseKey1` instead of value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said that you're storing this string in a database (or some external source)

```
apiResponse[""userDetails""][0][""userId""].ToString()
```

That's a bad idea, because that's C# code, and you certainly don't want to execute C# code that you load in from an external source.

At a minimum, store a path to the data you want, such as JSONPath, which is better suited for something like this.

```
string path = "$.userDetails[0].userId";
var userId = apiResponse.SelectToken(path).Value<string>();
// userId is 1001
```

`$.userDetails[0].userId` is safe to put in your database, because it's not *code* that you execute.

---

Granted it would be better to normalize all the data you receive and parse so you don't need to guess where the data is.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on storing & maintaining the main path of response in database. And yes it works as per expectations. Thank you `gunr2171` & `maccettura` for your help.